# Vim Ex Command History Ctrl-F not working

Tags: linux, vim, redhat-enterprise-linux, vi

I used to use Ctrl-F in my personal laptop to successfully get the command history pop-up in ex-mode but in my work PC, that no longer works. It just shows as ^F if I type Ctrl-F.

Vim Version is 7.4.629. This is hosted on RH linux server, so SSHing and using it via PuTTY.

Any way can I get this working?

Comment: "ex-mode" or "command-line mode"? Do `$ vim -Nu NONE`, what are the steps to replicate the issue?